# Cannot feed value of shape (10, 1, 1, 1) for Tensor 'Placeholder_1:0', which has shape '(?, 1)'

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow-datasets

I use tensorflow to build a CNN based oin RGB image which size are 224*172. Here is the network I build:

```
def deepnn(x):
  """deepnn builds the graph for a deep net for classifying digits.

  Args:
    x: an input tensor with the dimensions (N_examples, 784), where 784 is the
    number of pixels in a standard MNIST image.

  Returns:
    A tuple (y, keep_prob). y is a tensor of shape (N_examples, 10), with values
    equal to the logits of classifying the digit into one of 10 classes (the
    digits 0-9). keep_prob is a scalar placeholder for the probability of
    dropout.
  """
  # Reshape to use within a convolutional neural net.
  # Last dimension is for "features" - there is only one here, since images are
  # grayscale -- it would be 3 for an RGB image, 4 for RGBA, etc.
  depth = 3
  with tf.name_scope('reshape'):
    x_image = tf.reshape(x, [-1, 224, 172, depth])

  # First convolutional layer - maps one grayscale image to 32 feature maps.
  with tf.name_scope('conv1'):
    W_conv1 = weight_variable([5, 5, depth, 32])
    b_conv1 = bias_variable([32])
    h_conv1 = tf.nn.relu(conv2d(x_image, W_conv1) + b_conv1)

  # Pooling layer - downsamples by 2X.
  with tf.name_scope('pool1'):
    h_pool1 = max_pool_2x2(h_conv1)

  # Second convolutional layer -- maps 32 feature maps to 64.
  with tf.name_scope('conv2'):
    W_conv2 = weight_variable([5, 5, 32, 64])
    b_conv2 = bias_variable([64])
    h_conv2 = tf.nn.relu(conv2d(h_pool1, W_conv2) + b_conv2)

  # Second pooling layer.
  with tf.name_scope('pool2'):
    h_pool2 = max_pool_2x2(h_conv2)

  # Fully connected layer 1 -- after 2 round of downsampling, our 28x28 image
  # is down to 7x7x64 feature maps -- maps this to 1024 features.
  with tf.name_scope('fc1'):
    # W_fc1 = weight_variable([7 * 7 * 64, 1024])
    W_fc1 = weight_variable([56 * 42 * 64, 1024])

    b_fc1 = bias_variable([1024])

    h_pool2_flat = tf.reshape(h_pool2, [-1, 56 * 42 * 64])
    h_fc1 = tf.nn.relu(tf.matmul(h_pool2_flat, W_fc1) + b_fc1)

  # Dropout - controls the complexity of the model, prevents co-adaptation of
  # features.
  with tf.name_scope('dropout'):
    keep_prob = tf.placeholder(tf.float32)
    h_fc1_drop = tf.nn.dropout(h_fc1, keep_prob)

  # Map the 1024 features to 10 classes, one for each digit
  with tf.name_scope('fc2'):
    W_fc2 = weight_variable([1024, 1])
    b_fc2 = bias_variable([1])

    y_conv = tf.matmul(h_fc1_drop, W_fc2) + b_fc2
  return y_conv, keep_prob


def conv2d(x, W):
  """conv2d returns a 2d convolution layer with full stride."""
  return tf.nn.conv2d(x, W, strides=[1, 1, 1, 1], padding='SAME')


def max_pool_2x2(x):
  """max_pool_2x2 downsamples a feature map by 2X."""
  return tf.nn.max_pool(x, ksize=[1, 2, 2, 1],
                        strides=[1, 2, 2, 1], padding='SAME')


def weight_variable(shape):
  """weight_variable generates a weight variable of a given shape."""
  initial = tf.truncated_normal(shape, stddev=0.1)
  return tf.Variable(initial)


def bias_variable(shape):
  """bias_variable generates a bias variable of a given shape."""
  initial = tf.constant(0.1, shape=shape)
  return tf.Variable(initial)


def main(_):
  # Import data
  V0Dataset = dr.read_data_sets(FLAGS.data_dir, one_hot=True)

  # Create the model
  x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, 224*172*3])

  # Define loss and optimizer
  y_ = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, 1])

  # Build the graph for the deep net
  y_conv, keep_prob = deepnn(x)
```

When I try to train my network I get that error:

```
Cannot feed value of shape (10, 1, 1, 1) for Tensor 'Placeholder_1:0', which has shape '(?, 1)'
```

I think there is a problem in the shape of my structure or more probably a problem in the shape of my dataset.

There problem happends in that part of the code:

```
 with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
    for i in range(100):
      batch = V0Dataset.train.next_batch(10)
      train_step.run(feed_dict={x: batch[0], y_: batch[1], keep_prob: 0.5}) ##### error
```

Edit: Here is the update  of modification I made.

```
with tf.name_scope('reshape'):
    x_image = tf.reshape(x, [-1, 224, 172, 1])#(x, [-1, 28, 28, 1])

  # First convolutional layer - maps one grayscale image to 32 feature maps.
  with tf.name_scope('conv1'):
    W_conv1 = weight_variable([5, 5, 1, 32])#([5, 5, 1, 32])
    b_conv1 = bias_variable([32])
    h_conv1 = tf.nn.relu(conv2d(x_image, W_conv1) + b_conv1)

  # Pooling layer - downsamples by 2X.
  with tf.name_scope('pool1'):
    h_pool1 = max_pool_2x2(h_conv1)

  # Second convolutional layer -- maps 32 feature maps to 64.
  with tf.name_scope('conv2'):
    W_conv2 = weight_variable([5, 5, 32, 64])
    b_conv2 = bias_variable([64])
    h_conv2 = tf.nn.relu(conv2d(h_pool1, W_conv2) + b_conv2)

  # Second pooling layer.
  with tf.name_scope('pool2'):
    h_pool2 = max_pool_2x2(h_conv2)

  # Fully connected layer 1 -- after 2 round of downsampling, our 28x28 image
  # is down to 7x7x64 feature maps -- maps this to 1024 features.
  with tf.name_scope('fc1'):
    W_fc1 = weight_variable([28 * 43 * 64, 1024])
    b_fc1 = bias_variable([1024])

    h_pool2_flat = tf.reshape(h_pool2, [-1, 28*43*64])
    h_fc1 = tf.nn.relu(tf.matmul(h_pool2_flat, W_fc1) + b_fc1)

  # Dropout - controls the complexity of the model, prevents co-adaptation of
  # features.
  with tf.name_scope('dropout'):
    keep_prob = tf.placeholder(tf.float32)
    h_fc1_drop = tf.nn.dropout(h_fc1, keep_prob)

  # Map the 1024 features to 10 classes, one for each digit
  with tf.name_scope('fc2'):
    W_fc2 = weight_variable([1024, 2])
    b_fc2 = bias_variable([2])

    y_conv = tf.matmul(h_fc1_drop, W_fc2) + b_fc2
  return y_conv, keep_prob


def conv2d(x, W):
  """conv2d returns a 2d convolution layer with full stride."""
  return tf.nn.conv2d(x, W, strides=[1, 1, 1, 1], padding='SAME')


def max_pool_2x2(x):
  """max_pool_2x2 downsamples a feature map by 2X."""
  return tf.nn.max_pool(x, ksize=[1, 2, 2, 1],
                        strides=[1, 2, 2, 1], padding='SAME')


def weight_variable(shape):
  """weight_variable generates a weight variable of a given shape."""
  initial = tf.truncated_normal(shape, stddev=0.1)
  return tf.Variable(initial)


def bias_variable(shape):
  """bias_variable generates a bias variable of a given shape."""
  initial = tf.constant(0.1, shape=shape)
  return tf.Variable(initial)


def main(_):
  # Import data
  V0Dataset = dr.read_data_sets(FLAGS.data_dir, one_hot=True)

  # Create the model
  x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, 224*172])

  # Define loss and optimizer
  y_ = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, 2])
  print("logits shape {}".format(y_))


  # Build the graph for the deep net
  y_conv, keep_prob = deepnn(x)



  with tf.name_scope('loss'):
    cross_entropy = tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(labels=y_,
                                                            logits=y_conv)
  cross_entropy = tf.reduce_mean(cross_entropy)

  with tf.name_scope('adam_optimizer'):
    train_step = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(1e-4).minimize(cross_entropy)

  with tf.name_scope('accuracy'):
    correct_prediction = tf.equal(tf.argmax(y_conv, 1), tf.argmax(y_, 1))
    correct_prediction = tf.cast(correct_prediction, tf.float32)

  accuracy = tf.reduce_mean(correct_prediction)

  graph_location = tempfile.mkdtemp()
  print('Saving graph to: %s' % graph_location)
  train_writer = tf.summary.FileWriter("/tmp/tensorflow/")
  train_writer.add_graph(tf.get_default_graph())


  with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
    for i in range(100):
      batch = V0Dataset.train.next_batch(10)
      # print("----size0 {}".format(batch[0]))
      # print("----size1 {}".format(batch[1]))
      # print("----size2 {}".format(len(batch[0][0])))
      # print("batch {}".format(batch))
    #   if i % 100 == 0:
    #     train_accuracy = accuracy.eval(feed_dict={
    #         x: batch[0], y_: batch[1], keep_prob: 1.0})
    #     print('step %d, training accuracy %g' % (i, train_accuracy))
      # print("batch {}".format(batch[1]))
      # batch1 = batch[1].reshape(20,2)
      # print("batch {}".format(batch1))
      a =  batch[1];
      a = a.reshape(10,2)
      train_step.run(feed_dict={x: batch[0], y_: a, keep_prob: 0.5})

    # print('test accuracy %g' % accuracy.eval(feed_dict={
    #     x: V0Dataset.test.images, y_: V0Dataset.test.labels, keep_prob: 1.0}))

if __name__ == '__main__':
  parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
  parser.add_argument('--data_dir', type=str,
                      default='/tmp/tensorflow/mnist/input_data',
                      help='Directory for storing input data')
  FLAGS, unparsed = parser.parse_known_args()
  tf.app.run(main=main, argv=[sys.argv[0]] + unparsed)
```

And the error I get:

```
logits shape Tensor("Placeholder_1:0", shape=(?, 2), dtype=float32)
Saving graph to: /tmp/tmptzko8so7
2018-01-16 17:03:23.257533: I tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:137] Your CPU supports instructions that this TensorFlow binary was not compiled to use: SSE4.1 SSE4.2 AVX AVX2 FMA
start 0  batch_size 10
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 1323, in _do_call
    return fn(*args)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 1302, in _run_fn
    status, run_metadata)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/errors_impl.py", line 473, in __exit__
    c_api.TF_GetCode(self.status.status))
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InvalidArgumentError: logits and labels must be same size: logits_size=[20,2] labels_size=[10,2]
     [[Node: loss/SoftmaxCrossEntropyWithLogits = SoftmaxCrossEntropyWithLogits[T=DT_FLOAT, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0"](loss/Reshape, loss/Reshape_1)]]

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "deep_charging_station_train.py", line 238, in <module>
    tf.app.run(main=main, argv=[sys.argv[0]] + unparsed)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/platform/app.py", line 48, in run
    _sys.exit(main(_sys.argv[:1] + flags_passthrough))
  File "deep_charging_station_train.py", line 227, in main
    train_step.run(feed_dict={x: batch[0], y_: a, keep_prob: 0.5})
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 2042, in run
    _run_using_default_session(self, feed_dict, self.graph, session)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 4490, in _run_using_default_session
    session.run(operation, feed_dict)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 889, in run
    run_metadata_ptr)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 1120, in _run
    feed_dict_tensor, options, run_metadata)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 1317, in _do_run
    options, run_metadata)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 1336, in _do_call
    raise type(e)(node_def, op, message)
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InvalidArgumentError: logits and labels must be same size: logits_size=[20,2] labels_size=[10,2]
     [[Node: loss/SoftmaxCrossEntropyWithLogits = SoftmaxCrossEntropyWithLogits[T=DT_FLOAT, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0"](loss/Reshape, loss/Reshape_1)]]

Caused by op 'loss/SoftmaxCrossEntropyWithLogits', defined at:
  File "deep_charging_station_train.py", line 238, in <module>
    tf.app.run(main=main, argv=[sys.argv[0]] + unparsed)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/platform/app.py", line 48, in run
    _sys.exit(main(_sys.argv[:1] + flags_passthrough))
  File "deep_charging_station_train.py", line 192, in main
    logits=y_conv)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/nn_ops.py", line 1783, in softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits
    precise_logits, labels, name=name)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/gen_nn_ops.py", line 4364, in _softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits
    name=name)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/op_def_library.py", line 787, in _apply_op_helper
    op_def=op_def)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 2956, in create_op
    op_def=op_def)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 1470, in __init__
    self._traceback = self._graph._extract_stack()  # pylint: disable=protected-access

InvalidArgumentError (see above for traceback): logits and labels must be same size: logits_size=[20,2] labels_size=[10,2]
     [[Node: loss/SoftmaxCrossEntropyWithLogits = SoftmaxCrossEntropyWithLogits[T=DT_FLOAT, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0"](loss/Reshape, loss/Reshape_1)]]
```

Edit:

I find the solution. Apparently the input size has to habe the same width and height. I put width=height=100 and Now it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Error is due to the fact that tensor that you are feeding into placeholder **y_** is not matching.

```
V0Dataset = dr.read_data_sets(FLAGS.data_dir, one_hot=True)
```

In the above line, you enabled one_hot encoding so if you are doing multi-class classification then after executing `batch = V0Dataset.train.next_batch(10)` you will get a list of size "**1 x class_size**" in batch[1].

For example, if you are doing 10-way classification then output of y_ after next_batch() call will be something like [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0] indicating this input belongs to first class.

So change this line of code `y_ = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, 1])`. Replace this 1 with number of output classes.

Comment: There is only one output. The output is the fact that an object on the image own to the class. Therare no 10 output.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that your labels have the wrong shape. Just reshape then with numpy.

```
labels =  np.reshape(batch[1],(10,1))
```

Comment: In fact the problem comes from the structure of the CNN, there are problem in the size of layer. I try to use the deep mnist tutorial and modify the shape according to the input image (224x172). So how should be the internal structure of the CNN with my input?

Comment: I don't understand how you think the problem is with the CNN. At least that error is regarding to the labels (Placeholder_1) and it seems that the shape of the input tensor (labels) is different from what is expected. For me it makes sense that it expects (?,1) and it totally seems wrong a shape of (10,1,1,1). Have you tried the reshape as I've said? In that case, do you get a new error?

Comment: Indeed there was a problem of input size as you tell it. Now the problem comes from the shape of CNN. How to know thé shape of internal structure with my input ?

Comment: I would recommend you to create the graph using first iPython so you can see clearly where is the shape mismatch. Otherwise, you can also take the graph (maybe tf.get_default_graph()) and do graph.get_operations(), and check them one by one (operation.outputs) and you can see the shape in there.

Comment: I looked at the graph with tensorboard and nothing special is visible. Infact I don t understand because first I use the deep mnist example with 28x28 images and I modify the size of the input

Comment: I try the same dataset reader and binary file generator  with 28x28  deep mnist example and it works. For me the problem is in the shape of my modified 224x172  image neural networks.